# Pass sld env parameter with openlayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

Is there a way to pass sld env parameter with openlayers 3? 
It works to pass the env parameter with a normal getmap-request. Doesn´t openlayers support the env parameter?
I used this example http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/substitution.html

The problem is that I have to style a wms based on features that occured within the last 24 hours and 4 days, so I have to pass the exact timestamps.

Comment: How are you passing the SLD to GeoServer, can you give an example request?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
url: 'http://ip:port/geoserver/wms',
params: {'LAYERS': 'workspace:layername'/*,'ENV': 'key1:value1;key2:value2'*/},
serverType: 'geoserver',
crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});

var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: wmsSource
});

wmsSource.updateParams({ENV:'key1:value1;key2:value2'});

//or another way is, you can specify it at the time 
// of source object creation in it's params.
```

You can get more information here:

```
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('submitcolor').addEventListener('click', function () {

    debugger;
    var layer = document.getElementById("layers").value;
    //var value_layer = layer.options[layer.selectedIndex].value;

    let index = layersaArray.findIndex(function (val) {
        //debugger
        return val.A.title == layer
    });

    hexa = document.getElementById('pickcolor').value;
    color = hexa.substring(1)
    //console.log(color)

    var style_1 = `color:${color};name:triangle;size:12`
    map.getLayers().getArray()[index].getSource().updateParams({ env: style_1 });
});
```

Comment: How does this fix the pass the exact timestamps requirement?

Comment: Answers should include words which explain the solution.